# Cross-compiling ocaml apps for ARM

Tags: arm, ocaml, cross-compiling, touchscreen, angstrom-linux

I'm cross-compiling a touchscreen driver, which comes with an ocaml calibration application.

I'm trying to compile the driver and the application for ARM, in particular, the Beagleboard, running Angström.

It goes like this:

```
^_^[raziel@Bebop zytouch-driver-20081121]$ source /usr/local/angstrom/arm/environment-setup 
^_^[raziel@Bebop zytouch-driver-20081121]$ make CC=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes   -c -o daemon/config.o daemon/config.c
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes   -c -o daemon/util.o daemon/util.c
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes   -c -o daemon/debug.o daemon/debug.c
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes   -c -o daemon/zytouch_usb.o daemon/zytouch_usb.c
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes   -c -o daemon/zytouchd.o daemon/zytouchd.c
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc daemon/config.o daemon/util.o daemon/debug.o daemon/zytouch_usb.o daemon/zytouchd.o -lX11 -lXtst -lusb -lm -o zytouch-daemon
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/version.ml -o calibrate/version.cmx
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/util.ml -o calibrate/util.cmx
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/config.ml -o calibrate/config.cmx
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/orientation.ml -o calibrate/orientation.cmx
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/tscalibrate.ml -o calibrate/tscalibrate.cmx
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate extLib.cmxa str.cmxa unix.cmxa lablgtk.cmxa cairo_lablgtk.cmxa cairo.cmxa gtkInit.cmx calibrate/version.cmx calibrate/util.cmx calibrate/config.cmx calibrate/orientation.cmx calibrate/tscalibrate.cmx -o zytouch-calibrate
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /tmp/camlstartup71ef32.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /tmp/camlstartup71ef32.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
/tmp/camlstartup71ef32.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error during linking
make: *** [zytouch-calibrate] Error 2
```

I'm stuck in that `Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)` error.

The Makefile looks like this:

```
(...)
OFLAGS = -cc ${CC} -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A
OCAMLOPT = ocamlopt $(OFLAGS)

OCAML_INC =  -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate
OCAML_LIBS = $(OCAML_INC) extLib.cmxa str.cmxa unix.cmxa lablgtk.cmxa cairo_lablgtk.cmxa cairo.cmxa gtkInit.cmx

(...)    
config.cmx: util.cmx
orientation.cmx: config.cmx
tscalibrate.cmx: version.cmx util.cmx orientation.cmx config.cmx

%.cmx : %.ml
        $(OCAMLOPT) -c $(OCAML_INC) $< -o $@

%.mli : %.ml
        $(OCAMLC) -i $(OCAML_INC) $+
```

As `/usr/local/angstrom/arm/environment-setup` leaves `/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin` as the first element of my PATH, I tried to replace some programs with the ARM versions

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/ar
sudo ln -s /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-as /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/as
sudo ln -s /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ld /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/ld
```

However, after replacing `as`, the modules don't even compile

```
ocamlopt -cc arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -cclib -lcairo -cclib -lextlib -cclib -llablgtk2 -warn-error A -c -I +lablgtk2 -I +cairo -I +extlib -I calibrate calibrate/version.ml -o calibrate/version.cmx
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:31: Error: alignment too large: 15 assumed
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:35: Error: bad instruction `movl $camlVersion__3,%eax'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:36: Error: bad instruction `movl %eax,camlVersion'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:37: Error: bad instruction `movl $camlVersion__2,%eax'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:38: Error: bad instruction `movl %eax,camlVersion+4'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:39: Error: bad instruction `movl $camlVersion__1,%eax'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:40: Error: bad instruction `movl %eax,camlVersion+8'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:41: Error: bad instruction `movl $1,%eax'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:42: Error: bad instruction `ret'
/tmp/camlasm41bb77.s:43: Error: unrecognized symbol type ""
File "calibrate/version.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Assembler error, input left in file /tmp/camlasm41bb77.s
make: *** [calibrate/version.cmx] Error 2
```

I'm pretty sure it must be a very stupid error, but I can't find documentation on how to do this properly. Does anyone know what could be failing?

The source code of the driver I'm trying to build can be found [here](http://www.mega-nerd.com/Zytouch/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ocaml currently doesn't support cross-compilation, and passing -cc option will not make it magically cross-compile to arm. There are some patches floating around that make it possible, but nothing official. I remember using patched ocamlopt and it worked ok for simple programs. But in this case you will also need to cross-compile all dependent libraries and this can be quite a bit of a task.

I think your best solution is to either :

- build natively in arm qemu (this is quite easy, there are prebuilt debian images [available](http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_arm_qemu.php))
- build a bytecode binary of calibration application (bytecode is portable between architectures but requires the same version of ocaml installed on the target) and install required stub libraries (the ones that contain C code for bindings to gtk,cairo,etc) on arm (built natively or from packages)

Comment: I'm trying the first option, as the Angstrom distribution doesn't have an ocaml package. However, I can't seem to find ocamlopt in the Debian Squeeze ARM machine I'm using (they can be found readily available [here](http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armel/)).

According to [this](http://old.nabble.com/Bug-377499%3A-ocaml-nox%3A--usr-bin-ocamlopt-missing-in-ocaml-nox_3.09.2-5_s390.deb-td5243672.html), ocamlopt is not available for ARM, which just made my day a little more sad.
Do you happen to know a workaround for this?

Comment: ocaml in squeeze (3.11.2) indeed doesn't have ocamlopt for ARM, but 3.12.1 does, so just enable testing repository or build it from source (very easy). Also note that next ocaml release will have brand new arm code generator - it is already available in svn trunk if you feel brave.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not replaced all of the toolchain with the cross-compilation toolchain. `movl %eax,camlVersion` is a typical x86 instruction and not something you would see in ARM code. I usually get your errors when I forget to do a clean between building code for different architectures.

Comment: I removed the source directory, unpacked it again, and double-checked there were no stray binaries, but nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is probably not the source. From your logs it seems like the ocamlopt command produces x86 code instead of arm code.  The answer by ygrek also seems to suggest that ocaml does not support cross-compilation.